# JMETER: we are trying to return array variable as output from BeanShell Processor

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

Is it possible ? Can someone provide us with a sample code? We have a beanshell preprocessor returning a set of variables to the JMX script. Can we return a array instead?

Answer (score 2):

Following options are available:

1. [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) - stores an arbitrary Java Object into a JMeter Variable like below:

   ```
   List myList = new ArrayList();
   myList.add("something");
   myList.add("something else");
   vars.putObject("myList", myList);
   ```

[image: vars.putObject()]

2. [props.put()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put(K,%20V)) or [props.putAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) - the same but for JMeter Properties instead of JMeter Variables
3. Use [bsh.shared](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) namespace like:

   In one sampler:

   ```
   int [] array = new int {1,2,3};
   bsh.shared.myArray = array;
   ```

   In another sampler:

   ```
   int [] array = bsh.shared.myArray;
   ```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for additional information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.